# Как скопировать элементы из массива ОТ и ДО?

Tags: c#, массивы

Допустим есть массив `{'1','2','3','4','5'}`
Нужно вырезать с `1` элемента по `3` элемент например (при этом элемент с этим номером не включится в вырезанную часть).

В общем нужен аналог метода **slice** из `JavaScript` .

Решение:

```
char[] arr = {'1','2','3','4','5'};
            string result = new string(arr);
            result.Substring(1, 3);
```

Comment: Почему сами не написали?))

Comment: Я только изучаю c# и не смог найти похожего метода к сожалению.

Comment: Повторяю вопрос, почему вы сами не написали :)? *Внимание: вопрос не про то нашли ли вы метод в c#*

Comment: Потому что не понимаю как правильно это реализовать.

Comment: Ладно, тогда продолжайте учить C#, дальше вы дойдёте то циклов, как только вы дойдёте до них в листочек напишите кейсы того как работает `slice` в JavaScript (с отрицательными, положительными и с числами с плавающей запятой), дальше попробуйте реализовать это через циклы (не забываем про проверки). Если не получится, пришлите имеющийся ответ, вам помогут и укажут где вы сделали ошибки, может даже пришлют правильный ответ для вас, а на данный момент ваш "вопрос" похож на домашнее задание которое вы просите сделать за себя.

Comment: Спасибо за отклик)
Попробую что-то придумать, но думаю через List будт проще чем ерез циклы.

Comment: Не за что :) Рад что вы хотите попробовать что-то сделать. Вопрос если что можно отредактировать кнопкой [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1477662/edit), возможно что ваш вопрос будет закрыт к моменту вашего прибытия, при правке вопроса отметьте галочку которая будет чуть ниже редактирования вашего вопроса чтобы ваш вопрос заново открыли.

Comment: `var result = items[1..3]; // { "b","c" } ` ([Indices and ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/ranges-indexes))

Comment: @ΝNL993 Если есть готовые библиотечные или языковые методы - лучше пользоваться ими, а не на каждый чих писать по собственному велосипеду.

Comment: @Kromster справедливо, но если использовать библиотеки, то у тебя будут "библиотечные знания", а не знания по языку и его особенностям.

Comment: @ΝNL993 Ну, тут двояко. По-хорошему нужно уметь и то и это. Библиотеки - это тоже неотъемлемая часть языка, зачастую они помогают ускорить разработку в десятки раз.

Answer (score 5):

В C# есть несколько возможностей получить подмассив из массива:

1. С помощью встроенного языка запросов [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/):

   ```
    var subArray = arr.Skip(1).Take(3).ToArray();
   ```
2. С промежуточным использованием [списков](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netcore-3.0):

   ```
    var subArray = new List<char>(arr).GetRange(1, 3).ToArray();
   ```
3. Начиная с C# 8.0 вы можете использовать [Индексы и диапазоны](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/ranges-indexes):

   ```
    var subArray = arr[1..4];
   ```
4. Воспользоваться методом [Array.Copy()](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=net-7.0):

   ```
    var subArray = new char[3];
    Array.Copy(arr, 1, subArray, 0, 3);
   ```

---

Если в вашем коде получение подмассивов – частая операция, можете реализовать свой универсальный метод расширения, например так:

```
public static class ArrayExtensions
{
    public static T[] SubArray<T>(this T[] source, int index, int length)
    {
        T[] result = new T[length];
        Array.Copy(source, index, result, 0, length);
        return result;
    }
}
```

И затем использовать в коде так (причем работать будет с массивом любых типов за счет применения [обобщений](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics)):

```
var subArray = arr.SubArray(1, 3);

// массив чисел:
var intArray = new int[] { 0, 5, 10, 15, 20 };
intArray.SubArray(2, 2); // { 10, 15 }

// массив произвольных классов:
var myClassArray = new MyClass[10];
myClassArray.SubArray(6, 3);
```